# Scheduled Powershell task not being executed

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-1.0

I added a powershell script task on the Task Scheduler, set the user account to an Admin, then set the option to "Run only when user is logged on".

When I run this task manually, it executes correctly, but when I set the option to "Run whether user is logged on or not" it executes but never completes the task successfully.

"Run with highest privileges" is enabled on both scenario. What seems to be happening? How do I run the task without needing to be logged on?

EDIT:

Script copies file from a mounted drive to a local directory. When I run the script line by line using Powershell instead of the task scheduler, it works (both on normal and elevated Powershell).

```
$currentDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd');

gci "C:\some_directory" | where-object { ($_.Name -match $currentDate) -and (! $_.PSIsContainer) } | Copy-Item -Destination "Y:\" -force;
```

and on task scheduler: Powershell -Command "c:\scripts\my_script.ps1"

Comment: Could you add what the script do?

Comment: Add logging statements to the script so see in which step it fails. Use `Write-Eventlog` to log into the event log or `Add-Content` to log into a file.

Comment: @vonPryz hi, i'm doing a gc ... | where ... | copy-item can i add write-eventlog to that?

Comment: Edit your post and show the script.

Comment: updated the post for the script

Comment: With problems like this I've found adding a `Start-Transcript` with a known filename (that I know the identity running the script can write to) with plenty of logging in the script makes all the difference to determining what failed. In extreme cases [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can also help—but a lot of data to work through for even a trivial script.

Answer (score 0):

For error logging, the script needs to be splitted into more manageable chunks. An one-liner is hady for interactive sessions but are not easy for maintenance.

```
$currentDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$log = "c:\temp\logfile.txt"
$errorCount = $Error.Count

# Save the source files into an array
$files = @(gci "C:\some_directory" | ? {
  ($_.Name -match $currentDate) -and (! $_.PSIsContainer) 
})

# Log about source to see if $files is empty for some reason    
Add-Content $log $("Source file count: {0}" -f $files.Count)
# Check that Y: drive is available
Add-Content $log $("Testing access to destination: {0}" -f (test-path "y:\") )

$files | % {
  # Check the error count for new errors and log the message
  if($Error.Count -gt $errorCount) {
    Add-Content $log $Error
    $errorCount = $Error.Count
  }
  Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $(join-path "y:" $_.Name) -force
}
```

Comment: Copy-Item $_ -Destination "y:\" -force searches the script's folder for the files instead of C:\some_directory. I'm new with powershell so how do i do a Copy-Item $directory + $filename -Destination "Y:\" -force

Comment: @Bahamut, see updated `Copy-Item` command, which uses FullName and Name propeties.